# How to import the openjdk9 source code to visual studio 2017 after compilation in Windows 10l?

Tags: jvm

I tried to build the  openjdk9 source code in Windows 10 by the following commands

```
go to D:\jdk9\jdk9 with cygwin

./configure -with-freetype=/cygdrive/c/freetype -enable-debug -with-target-bits=64

make all
```

Finally it build successfully with messages :

```
Creating support/demos/image/jfc/Font2DTest/Font2DTest.jar
Creating support/demos/image/jfc/Metalworks/Metalworks.jar
Creating support/demos/image/jfc/Notepad/Notepad.jar
Creating support/demos/image/jfc/TableExample/TableExample.jar
Creating support/demos/image/jfc/TransparentRuler/TransparentRuler.jar
Creating support/demos/image/jfc/SampleTree/SampleTree.jar
Creating jre jimage
Creating jdk jimage
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.httpclient
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.httpclient
Finished building target 'all' in configuration 'windows-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug'
```

However how to import the project such as jdk or Hotspot to visual studio? There is neither no solution file nor project file generated,  also there is no create.bat file exist in folder \jdk9\hotspot\make (openjdk 8 has the file), so how to import the jdk/Hotspot source code to the visual studio 2017 to debug the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build VS Project Creator run the following command from the `openjdk9` top directory:

```
make hotspot-ide-project
```

In my case, the generated VS project files are located in:

```
.../openjdk9/build/windows-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/ide/hotspot-visualstudio
```

Finally, find the `jvm.vcxproj` file in the `hotspot-visualstudio` directory and open it.